# how to get distinct value in linq

Tags: c#, linq

i have used below linq query to join some table to get accurate data..

```
(from row in
  (from c in DbContext.Customer
   join cd in DbContext.CustomerDetails
   on c.Customer_Id equals cd.CustomerDetail_CustomerId
   join cp in DbContext.ProductPurchases
   on cd.CustomerDetail_OrgID equals cp.ProductPurchase_OrgID
   where cd.CustomerDetail_OrgId == OrganizationID --organization Id is common
   && c.Customer_Org_Id == OrganizationID
   && cp.ProductPurchase_OrgID == OrganizationID
   orderby cd.CustomerDetail_CreatedDate descending
   select new { c, cd, cp })
   select new CustomerDTO
   {
      CustomerId = row.cpd.CustomerDetail_CustomerID,
      CustomerName = row.c.Customer_LastName+", "+row.c.Customer_FirstName,
   }).ToList();
```

i have a small problem in CustomerDetail records i only want to get distinct records from the CustomerDetail based on the CustomerId....

CustomerDetail can have more than one records for the same CustomerId

please suggest how i can filter my query to get only distinct records from the CustomerDetail table

thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ provides the `Distinct` method. However, it uses the default equality comparer by default, or optionally one you specified.

I would recommend instead of using an anonymous type, define a class with the properties CustomerId and CustomerName, then override Equals.

```
public class DistinctCustomer
{
   public int CustomerId { get; set; }
   public string CustomerName { get; set; }

   public override bool Equals(object obj)
   {
        if (ReferenceEquals(obj, null)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;

        var other = obj as DistinctCustomer;

        if (other == null) return false;

        return CustomerId == other.CustomerId;
   }

   public override int GetHashCode()
   {
        return CustomerId.GetHashCode();
   }
}
```

and then

```
(from row in
  (from c in DbContext.Customer
   join cd in DbContext.CustomerDetails
   on c.Customer_Id equals cd.CustomerDetail_CustomerId
   join cp in DbContext.ProductPurchases
   on cd.CustomerDetail_OrgID equals cp.ProductPurchase_OrgID
   where cd.CustomerDetail_OrgId == OrganizationID --organization Id is common
   && c.Customer_Org_Id == OrganizationID
   && cp.ProductPurchase_OrgID == OrganizationID
   orderby cd.CustomerDetail_CreatedDate descending
   select new { c, cd, cp })
   select new DistinctCustomer
   {
      CustomerId = row.cpd.CustomerDetail_CustomerID,
      CustomerName = row.c.Customer_LastName+", "+row.c.Customer_FirstName,
   }).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: True, this will be required only if the same customer id, has more than one LastName/FirstName.  Otherwise anonymous types equals suffice in ensuring all properties are equal

Comment: Right, and he specifically stated he wants to check distinct only on CustomerId

Comment: hi thanks for ur comment i have already defined a class which have both the properties as you have mentioned.....it CustomerDTO

Comment: Or, create an IEqualityComparer<CustomerDTO> which will allow you to confine the 'equality by customer id' to this scenario specifically.

Comment: Yeah, in this particular case it might make sense to use a custom IEqualityComparer, since this method of determining equality might only be relevant to this query.

Answer (score 5):

You can implement a comparer class for your CustomerDetail(s)-Objects and then use the overloaded version, which accepts your comparer.

Something like this:

```
class CustomerDetailsComparer: IEqualityComparer<CustomerDetail>
{
    public bool Equals(CustomerDetail x, CustomerDetail y)
    {

        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            return false;

        return x.CustomerId == y.CustomerId;
    }


    public int GetHashCode(CustomerDetail cd)  
    {
         // Do something here
    }  
}


// ...

DbContext.CustomerDetails.Distinct(new CustomerDetailsComparer());
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use .Distinct() before `.ToList()`
I.e.

```
(from row in
  (from c in DbContext.Customer
   join cd in DbContext.CustomerDetails
   on c.Customer_Id equals cd.CustomerDetail_CustomerId
   join cp in DbContext.ProductPurchases
   on cd.CustomerDetail_OrgID equals cp.ProductPurchase_OrgID
   where cd.CustomerDetail_OrgId == OrganizationID --organization Id is common
   && c.Customer_Org_Id == OrganizationID
   && cp.ProductPurchase_OrgID == OrganizationID
   orderby cd.CustomerDetail_CreatedDate descending
   select new { c, cd, cp })
   select new 
   {
      CustomerId = row.cpd.CustomerDetail_CustomerID,
      CustomerName = row.c.Customer_LastName+", "+row.c.Customer_FirstName,
   }).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: That will find Distinct objects, not Distinct by a particular field.

Comment: hello @RJLohan i have made the changes according to answer specified above but still the same problem....it is not taking the distinct value

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
(--your code--).Distinct().ToList();
```